# CRM 2011 GROUP and COUNT

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to GROUP the CRM records that have the same "Owner" name and also get a count of the records for each GROUP. So I have a DLL that runs on a schedule and pulls the info down from CRM 2011. But I can't seem to get it to group and do a count of the records for each group. For example all the records with the Owner of "Bob" will say Bob you have X records. And any records with the Owner of "Ted" would say Ted you have X records, etc. For every owner there is. Any idea how to do this? This is what I have so far:

```
              var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                             join c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals c["systemuserid"] into opp
                             from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             //where ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Equals("100000002")
                             select new

                             {
                                 OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
                                 CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
                                 Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
                                 ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
                                 Source = !r.Contains("new_source") ? string.Empty : ((String)r["new_source"]),
                                 CreatedOn = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)r["createdon"]).ToShortDateString(),
                                 Eval = !r.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") || ((OptionSetValue)r["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString() == "100000000" ? "NA" : r.FormattedValues["new_distributorevaluation"].Substring(0, 2),
                                 EvalVal = !r.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") ? "100000000" : ((OptionSetValue)r["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString(),
                                 DistributorName = !r.Contains("new_channelpartner") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Name,
                                 Notes = !r.Contains("new_distributornotes") ? string.Empty : r["new_distributornotes"],
                                 EstimatedCloseDate = !r.Contains("estimatedclosedate") ? string.Empty : r["estimatedclosedate"],
                                 MaturityValue = !r.Contains("estimatedvalue") ? string.Empty : ((Money)r["estimatedvalue"]).Value.ToString(),
                                 SentToDistributorOn = !r.Contains("new_senttodistributoron") ? DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString() : ((DateTime)r["new_senttodistributoron"]).ToShortDateString(),
                                 LeadStatus = !r.Contains("new_leadstatus") ? string.Empty : ((OptionSetValue)r["new_leadstatus"]).Value.ToString(),
                                 EmailedToRSM = !r.Contains("new_emailedtorsm") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_emailedtorsm"],
                                 EmailedToDistributor = !r.Contains("new_emailedtodistributor") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_emailedtodistributor"],
                                 Owner = !r.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Name,
                                 OwnerEmail = !o.Contains("internalemailaddress") ? string.Empty : ((String)o["internalemailaddress"]),
                             }).ToArray();

            foreach (var distributor in linqQuery)
            {



                DateTime dtCreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime(distributor.CreatedOn);
                DateTime dtSentOn = Convert.ToDateTime(distributor.SentToDistributorOn);

                // New Lead Notification
                    if (((distributor.Owner.ToString() == distributor.Owner.ToString()) && (DateTime.Now - dtCreatedOn).Days <= 1) && (distributor.LeadStatus == "100000000") && ((distributor.EmailedToRSM == "No") || (distributor.EmailedToRSM == null)) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(distributor.Owner.ToString()) == false))
                    {

                        int count = 0;
                        count = count + 1;
                        string lBodyHTML = "";

                        lBodyHTML = "You have " + distributor.CustomerId.ToString() + " " + distributor.CreatedOn.ToString() + " " + count.ToString() + " new leads. Please review them for follow up or assignment.";

                        string smtpServer = Convert.ToString(Globals.HostSettings["SMTPServer"]);
                        string smtpAuthentication = Convert.ToString(Globals.HostSettings["SMTPAuthentication"]);
                        string smtpUsername = Convert.ToString(Globals.HostSettings["SMTPUsername"]);
                        string smtpPassword = Convert.ToString(Globals.HostSettings["SMTPPassword"]);
                        string xResult = Mail.SendMail("email@email.com", "email@email.com", "", "", MailPriority.High, "You have X new leads", MailFormat.Html, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, lBodyHTML, "", smtpServer, smtpAuthentication, smtpUsername, smtpPassword);

                    }
```

Any help would be awesome. I'm stuck right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic [has come up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433882/select-a-percentage-of-records-using-crm-2011-dynamic-entity/7453007#7453007), but the basic answer is that [you can't do this via LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations), but [you can via Microsoft's FetchXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx).  In fact, [the first example on `GROUP BY` in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#groupby) addresses the requirements of your example about as perfectly as any SDK can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var linqQuery =
    from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
    join c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("systemuser") on ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id equals c["systemuserid"]
    group r by ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Id into oop
    select new
    {
      Key = oop.Key,
      Count = oop.Count(),
      Opportunities = oop //contains the list of opportunities grouped by OwnerId
    };
```

`Opportunities` contains a collection of IGrouping
You must iterate through the collection `IEnumerable<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity>` to create the list of opportunities with the members you are interested. (the projection you made by using the new operator)

```
var outputOpportunities = new ArrayList();
foreach (IGrouping<Guid, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity> group in linqQuery)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity opportunity in group)
        outputOpportunities.Add
        (new
            {
                OpportunityId = !opportunity.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : opportunity["opportunityid"],
                CustomerId = !opportunity.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)opportunity["customerid"]).Name,
                Priority = !opportunity.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : opportunity.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
                ContactName = !opportunity.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)opportunity["new_contact"]).Name,
                Source = !opportunity.Contains("new_source") ? string.Empty : ((String)opportunity["new_source"]),
                CreatedOn = !opportunity.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)opportunity["createdon"]).ToShortDateString(),
                Eval = !opportunity.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") || ((OptionSetValue)opportunity["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString() == "100000000" ? "NA" : opportunity.FormattedValues["new_distributorevaluation"].Substring(0, 2),
                EvalVal = !opportunity.Contains("new_distributorevaluation") ? "100000000" : ((OptionSetValue)opportunity["new_distributorevaluation"]).Value.ToString(),
                DistributorName = !opportunity.Contains("new_channelpartner") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)opportunity["new_channelpartner"]).Name,
                Notes = !opportunity.Contains("new_distributornotes") ? string.Empty : opportunity["new_distributornotes"],
                EstimatedCloseDate = !opportunity.Contains("estimatedclosedate") ? string.Empty : opportunity["estimatedclosedate"],
                MaturityValue = !opportunity.Contains("estimatedvalue") ? string.Empty : ((Money)opportunity["estimatedvalue"]).Value.ToString(),
                SentToDistributorOn = !opportunity.Contains("new_senttodistributoron") ? DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString() : ((DateTime)opportunity["new_senttodistributoron"]).ToShortDateString(),
                LeadStatus = !opportunity.Contains("new_leadstatus") ? string.Empty : ((OptionSetValue)opportunity["new_leadstatus"]).Value.ToString(),
                EmailedToRSM = !opportunity.Contains("new_emailedtorsm") ? string.Empty : opportunity.FormattedValues["new_emailedtorsm"],
                EmailedToDistributor = !opportunity.Contains("new_emailedtodistributor") ? string.Empty : opportunity.FormattedValues["new_emailedtodistributor"],
                Owner = !opportunity.Contains("ownerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)opportunity["ownerid"]).Name,
                OwnerEmail = !opportunity.Contains("internalemailaddress") ? string.Empty : ((String)opportunity["internalemailaddress"])
            }
        );
}
```

Basically i took your query and added the `group by` operator and in the projection statement i put the count by ownerid.

Comment: Thanks! I Gave that a try and I get this error: "Error 5 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Guid,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments" Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I think I am closer. I am getting "Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Guid,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity>'" on this line "foreach (IGrouping<Guid, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity> group in linqQuery)" any idea? Thanks for your help!